# Accessing functions of another class

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

So I have a class called `GameScene` which has a function called `makeBackground`. In another class called I created an instance of it (GameScene) and called makeBackground as follows in the didMoveToView of the new class:

```
var gameSceneInstance:GameScene = GameScene()
gameSceneInstance.makeBackground()
```

However when I run it, nothing happens!

This is the function makeBackground:

```
 func makeBackground ()
    {
        let bgTxt       = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")
        let moveBg      = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -bgTxt.size().height, duration: 5)
        let replaceBg   = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: bgTxt.size().height, duration: 0)
        let moveBgAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBg, replaceBg]))

        //-----background-----
        for var i:CGFloat = 0 ; i<3; i++
        {
            bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTxt)
            bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: bgTxt.size().height/2 + bgTxt.size().height * i)
            bg.size.width = self.frame.width
            bg.runAction(moveBgAnimation)

            movingObjects.addChild(bg)
        }
    }
```

Do I have to copy and paste the `makeBackground` function into the new class to make it work?

Similarly, in the `didMoveToView` of the GameScene class, I have some sprites. Can I use them in this new class?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that *something* happens. The method is called and it is executed. There will be some trivial mistake. Is `GameScene` a `SKView`? Have you added that into the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

if you created an instance of the GameScene object and called the makeBackground function and nothing happened then there is something wrong with your code in the makeBackground function.

Also in another topic, instance objects which are created in a class are equeals of each other and cannot be used within each others methods unless they are specifically passed in.  Perhaps you can make a method in your GameScen object with which you could pass these sprites in either as a list of sprites or as individual sprites

Comment: If there was something wrong with the makeBackground function then it shouldn't work in the GameScene class right? However it works perfectly fine there.

Comment: Now I'm completely confused, is GameScene a static class or an instantiated class?  Where is it being called internally?  Also is there a viewport or some other output device which has been defined within the clas wherever makeBackground is being called from which has not been defined in the other class which you've created the instance object in?